# How to Install ELK Stack in AKS and How to SSH into Node in both (AKS and GKE)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, elk

I want to know how to ssh into nodes in both GKE and AKS and also how to install ELK stack in Kubernetes cluster.

Any links with step by step will be helpful for me.

Not able to connect with this command: `gcloud compute ssh <NODE_NAME> --zone <ZONE>`.

Comment: i am not sure why you want to ssh into node, it's how to run kubernetes cluster, you can use this chart to isntall ELK stack. https://github.com/elastic/helm-charts

Comment: not using helm chart can i have yaml file of that

Comment: Apply yaml using kubectl thn where you are facing issue ? Why need  ssh ?

Comment: Usually using Kubernetes you can't ssh to the individual nodes.  That's doubly true when running in a hosted cloud environment.  Also, consider that the nodes will frequently be managed by a cluster autoscaler: a node can be destroyed if it's underutilized, or if the cluster needs more capacity, a new node will be created, and this automation doesn't work well with manually logging into the nodes.

Answer (score 0):

That is the correct command to ssh into a GKE node, maybe your default project is wrong; I suggest you try with:

```
gcloud compute ssh "gke-node-name" --zone "your-zone" --project "your-cluster-project"
```

Now, if your goal is to deploy the ELK stack in your Kubernetes cluster, then there is no need to ssh into the nodes; you can easily use the [Official Elastic Docker images](https://www.docker.elastic.co/) and deploy them in your cluster as specified in the [Running the Elastic Stack on Kubernetes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elastic-stack-get-started/current/get-started-kubernetes.html#get-started-kubernetes) guide.

Additionally, you can take a look at this tutorial about [Deploying a containerized web application](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/hello-app).

Comment: yes there is no need to ssh into nodes for deploying ELK stack it was different scenario purpose i ask

Comment: got it @user17201361, was the information provided in the answer useful?